# POST request from Chrome Extension to App Engine received as GET request

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, post, google-chrome-extension, get

I am trying to send a minimal POST request from a Chrome Extension to a server hosted using Google App Engine. Here is my server code:

```
class Receive(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info('received a get')

    def post(self):
        logging.info('received a post')
```

Here is the Javascript code in my Chrome Extension:

```
$.post("http://perativ.com/receive");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "http://perativ.com/receive"
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://perativ.com/receive");
xhr.send();
```

I have the `<all_urls>` permission in my `manifest.json` file.

I included the three identical requests to show that nothing is working. When I run this Chrome Extension and then check the server logs at perativ.com, I get three lines that say: "received a get".

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see by the following command, the request to your website is being redirected from perativ.com to www.perativ.com using HTTP status code 301. When this redirect happens, POST is converted to GET.

To solve the issue, send the request to www.perativ.com instead of perativ.com, OR disable the redirect if it is within your reach.

```
$ curl -X POST http://perativ.com/receive -H 'Content-Length: 0'
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.perativ.com/receive">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Unfortunately, I tried changing all instances of "perativ.com/receive" to "www.perativ.com/receive," but I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: @Site Have you reloaded your extension after replacing the URLs? What you just described sounds impossible.

Comment: Ah no, that was it! You were completely right about switching to "www". I had no idea that redirects would convert POSTs to GETs. Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI if you ever want to redirect while preserving the HTTP method, use the 307 or 308 HTTP status code (308 is not supported as well as 307 though).